# show data from laravel controller to jstree

Tags: javascript, laravel, jstree

I need to get the data from laravel controller to jstree in blade.php.
I have all the data I need from controller in my blade file (  `echo json_encode($data);` ) but I need them as tree.

project table is connected with jstree table so when I click on project.show route  it shows project details with foreign jstree key (`tree_id`) and with this key i retrieve the jstree data as it shows in the function below

ProjectController

```
public function show($id)
{
    $project = Project::find($id);

    $tid = $project->tree_id;
    $node = TreeModel::where('tid', $tid)->first();
    $data = array();

    $data[] = array(
        'id' => $node->tid,
        'text' => $node->text,
        "children" => $this->getChildren($node->tid)
    );


    echo json_encode($data);
    return view('projects.show', compact('project'));
    }
```

Web.php:

```
    Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController');
```

Jstree function

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#jstree_demo").jstree({
   "core": {
       "check_callback": true,
       "data":  {
           'url':'???',
           'dataType':"json"
        }
  },.....
```

My results in show.blade.php is this output:

```
{
  "id": "j1_1",
  "text": "Folder_one",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "j1_2",
      "text": "New Paragraph",
      "type": "file",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "id": "j1_5",
      "text": "1",
      "type": "default",
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}]
```

and I need these results as a jstree

Comment: It sounds like the `???` should be the url that shows the `show.blade.php` template.

Comment: @Djave show.blade.php is under this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/2 , if write in "url" projects/{project}   (that is the show route) i get a 404 error